# Is there any free indexed journal that Geoscience students can publish?

Tags: geophysics, seismology

I am planning to publish a paper related in Geoscience/Geophysics/Seismology within scope of **Machine Learning/AI** in particular. Is there any Journal that provide free article publishing for postgraduate students? Low publishing fees should be fine as well.

Answer (score 2):

There has been a surge of [diamond open access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_open_access) (the best practice IMHO) geoscience journals recently, beginning with the pioneer Volcanica in my field (volcanology), and then followed by Tektonika (tectonics/structural geology), Geomorphica (geomorphology), Sedimentologika (sedimentology), among others. In your field, there is... [Seismica](https://seismica.library.mcgill.ca/)! Their [Scope page](https://seismica.library.mcgill.ca/policies#scope) includes:

> **Theoretical and computational seismology:** advances in seismology
> driven by numerical modeling including high-performance computing, by
> forward and inverse theories, uncertainty analysis and machine
> learning.

If cost (and open access!) are more important than impact factor to you, I'd encourage you to publish there.